# Полиморфизм: сохранение в динамическую структуру данных

Tags: c++

Начал изучать полиморфизм, есть непонимание.
Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка? 
Задача сохранить указатель базового класса на объект любого производного класса в динамическую структуру данных Вектор.

Структура: базовый абстрактный класс Device, производные USB, DVD, HDD, шаблонный Vector и класс PriceList (у который есть поле объект Vector v; и поле Device *p; методы данного класса будут вызываться в main).

После того как в методе AddDevice класса PriceList указатель базового абстрактного класса перенаправлен на объект производного, он передаётся в функцию Vector для заполнения массива данными в виде адреса на объект(USB), компилятор выдаёт ошибку?

error C2259: 'Device' : cannot instantiate abstract clas

> Device.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Device
{
protected:

    char name[15];
    char type[15];
    unsigned int size;
    int quantity;

public:

    Device();
    virtual ~Device() = 0;

    virtual void InputData();
};
```

> Device.cpp

```
#include "Device.h"


Device::Device()
{
    memset(this->name, 0, 15);
    memset(this->type, 0, 15);
    size = 0;
    quantity = 0;
}

Device:: ~Device()
{
    cout << "Destructor Device\n";
} 

void Device::InputData()
{
    if (cin.peek() == '\n')
        cin.get();

    RussianMessage("\nВведите наименование устройства: ");
    cin.getline(name, 14);

    RussianMessage("\nВведите тип устойства: ");
    cin.getline(type, 14);


    RussianMessage("\nВведите ёмкость носителя: ");
    cin >> size;

    RussianMessage("\nВведите количество носителей: ");
    cin >> quantity;

}
```

> USB.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Device.h"

class USB : public Device
{
    int speed;

public:

    USB();
    ~USB();

    void InputData();

};
```

> USB.cpp

```
#include "USB.h"

USB::USB()
{
    speed = 0;
}

USB::~USB()
{
    cout << "Destructor USB\n";
}


void USB::InputData()
{
    this->Device::InputData();
    RussianMessage("\nВведите скорость USB: ");
    cin >>speed;
}
```

> PriceList.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Vector.h"
#include"DVD.h"
#include"HDD.h"
#include"USB.h"

class PriceList
{
    Vector<Device> v;
    Device *p;
    int count;

public:

    void AddPortable();       
};
```

> PriceList.cpp

```
void PriceList::AddPortable()
{
    system("cls");
    RussianMessage("Сделайе выбор\n");
    RussianMessage("1. Добавить элемент USB\n2. Добавить элемене DVD\n3. Добавить элемент HDD\n");

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    RussianMessage("Введите количество элеменов для добавления в список: ");
    int countElem;
    cin >> countElem;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case usb:
        for (int i = 0; i < countElem; i++)
        {
            p = new USB;
            p->InputData();
            **v.Add(*p);**
        }
        break;      
    }

}
```

> Vector.h

```
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::Add(const T& item)
{
    T *temp = new T[this->size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        temp[i] = this->vect[i];
    temp[size] = item;
    delete[] vect;
    vect = temp;
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в вашем же тексте четко сказано

> Задача сохранить **указатель** базового класса на объект любого производного класса в динамическую структуру данных Вектор.

Ваш же `PriceList` содержит

```
Vector<Device> v;
```

Я догадываюсь, что `Vector` - это какой-то доморощенный контейнер типа `std::vector`. Если так, то `Vector<Device>` уже противоречит вашей же постановке задачи. Как вы сам сказали, вам нужен вектор *указателей*, т.е. в простейшем случае это будет

```
Vector<Device *> v;
```

(А еще лучше воспользоваться "умными" указателями.)

Ваша же попытка создания `Vector<Device>` приведет только к попытке инстанциирования объектов класса `Device`, что, разумеется, невозможно. Именно об этом вам говорит компилятор.

Ваши `memset`ы в конструкторе `Device` тоже приводят в ужас. В С++ это делается так

```
Device::Device() : name(), type(), size(), quantity()
  {}
```

Отдельно непонятно, почему на `name` вы ссылаетесь, как на `this->name`, а на `size` как просто `size`...